# "Why people don't like it" vs "Why wouldn't people like it."

Tags: sentence-structure

Yesterday I saw a video on Youtube. There's an English native speaker, but he can also speak Chinese fluently. The video is quite interesting. He is judging the English speaking ability of some famous Chinese company's CEO.

I have a question about what he said in the video. He mentioned that *"why people don't like it"* is not the right way to say it, and that we should use *"why wouldn't people like it"* instead. Is there anyone who can tell me what's the difference between those two sentences?

Comment: Could you please link to the video, or give us more context?  "Why people don't like it" is fine, but usually as a phrase as in, *"I don't understand why people don't like it."*  It's not grammatical as a question.

Comment: Please use this **[edit]** link to add a link to the video to your question. Without that, we have no idea whether there is _any_ difference between the two sentences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an unknown speaker in an unknown video.

Comment: Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CCBnSlYKOE, 12:05

Answer (score 2):

I'd need to know more about the context in which the speaker said those two phrases to give you a confident answer, but here's an educated guess.

If you want to ask for an explanation about why people might not like something that they haven't tried yet, you would say, "Why wouldn't people like it?"

An error commonly made by people learning English is to instead say, "Why people don't like it?"

## Word order

There are two problems with the second sentence. First, the word order isn't appropriate for the intended question. To make it a question, you need to reverse the order of *people* and *don't*: "Why **don't people** like it?" Without the reversed word order, a listener hears "why people don't like it" as a relative clause—that is, like a big noun built on *why,* which needs to be part of a larger sentence, like this:

> The screeching sound is **why people don't like it**.

People mentally parse that sentence in the same overall structure as "(The parakeet) is (my pet)":

> (The parakeet) is (my pet).
>   (The screeching sound) is (why people don't like it).

When you reverse *people* and *don't,* it's understood as a complete sentence on its own, asking a question:

> Why **don't people** like it?

## Hypothetical vs. known

The second difference between "Why wouldn't people like it?" and "Why don't people like it?" is that in the first sentence, "people don't like it" is only a hypothesis, and in the second sentence, the speaker knows that people don't like it. Some imaginary contexts might make the difference clear:

> John: "I am thinking of buying Denise a parakeet for her birthday. Do you think she **would like it**?"
>   Helen: "No, I don't think she **would like it**."
>   John: "**Why wouldn't she like it**?"
>   Helen: "Denise **doesn't like** screeching."

John hasn't yet decided whether to buy Denise a parakeet. It's still only an imaginary possibility. Neither John nor Helen *knows* whether Denise will be happy if she receives a parakeet for her birthday. Helen is only making an educated guess. When John and Helen put **would** in front of the verb, they are talking about a *consequence* of a hypothesis—the hypothesis that John gives Denise a parakeet for her birthday. But Helen does know that Denise doesn't like screeching. Because that is a known fact, Helen says **doesn't like** rather than **wouldn't like**.

Here's a slightly different situation:

> John: "I bought Denise a parakeet for her birthday."
>   Helen: "Does she like it?"
>   John: "No, she doesn't like it."
>   Helen: "**Why doesn't she like it**?"
>   John: "The screeching sound is **why she doesn't like it**."

This time, both John and Helen already know that Denise doesn't like the parakeet. So, they don't say **would**.

## Why ESL learners make these mistakes

Some languages do not require this hypothetical/known distinction to be indicated for every verb. English does. The verb of a sentence always has "mood": whether it's a description of a known fact (or a question about a known fact), a hypothesis, a command, etc. "Why wouldn't people like it?" is in the [*conditional mood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood): it asks for a consequence of a hypothesis (assuming that people don't like it, why would they dislike it?). Sometimes the grammatical mood is expressed in subtle ways, but every sentence in English *does* specify a mood. It's the same as the way every English sentence specifies a tense.

If you're coming from a language where the same kind of information is optional, you might expect that you can ignore it in English. If you ignore it, though, you are out of sync with the language. People can probably still understand you, but you're missing crucial information, and sometimes it makes people wonder if there has been some misunderstanding.

Also, in some languages, you make a statement into a question not by changing the word order, but by adding a particle, adding "not ___" after the verb, or using special pronouns—as in Mandarin! So, if your first language is Mandarin, you have to focus carefully on subtleties of word order.

When you're a beginner learning a new language, it takes great mental effort just to understand the words or choose the right words when speaking. At that stage, it's probably too hard to *also* keep track of all the subtleties of a foreign grammar. So, it's natural for beginners in English to ignore word order, mood, and tense. After a lot of practice, though, understanding them and making your own choices about them becomes easier. At some point during your learning of English, you will probably need to focus very closely on these things in order to master them.

Comment: This is a useful answer for posterity, but without _seeing the actual video_ which the OP for some reason will not link to, we have no reason to assume that _"why people don't like it"_ isn't perfectly proper in context! (For reference, a speech in "English" by Lei Jun is **[here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-pQ4YdOpnE)** This is a widely ridiculed speech and has been circulating among Chinese viewers like wildfire. I suspect the OP refers to this or similar.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant Well, if this answer turns out not to be on target, I can delete it and re-post it the next time someone brings up essentially this same problem. Your [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133706/133708#comment270180_133708) yesterday has inspired me to try explaining this without the usual attempt to spell out exhaustive syntactic rules complete with the latest jargon. (Actually, we do have _some_ reason: it's a very common error, I think especially for people coming from languages like Mandarin, and the speaker said he was describing an error.)

Answer (score 0):

*"Why don't people like it?"* is asking a question AFTER some people have said that they don't like it.

*"Why wouldn't people like it?"* could be asking the question after some people have said that they don't like it, but it could also be asking the question BEFORE any people say if they do or do not like it.  For example, a company employee might ask other staff *"Why wouldn't people like it?"* to try to identify aspects of a new product that buyers may not like, before those buyers ever get to see the product (and then try to improve those aspects before the product goes on sale).

But without a link to the original video it is hard to judge the exact meaning intended.

Answer (score -1):

"Why people don't like it" is used when there is no question that someone  doesn't like something. "Why people don't like it is because your product is expensive and of poor quality."  "Why wouldn't people like it?" is a question asking for thoughts: "Why wouldn't people like this product?  I think it's great." Both are grammatically correct; the intonation and the meaning is different.